# What's the meaning of field bitVectors in column statistics(Hive)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, statistics, hive-metastore

[column statistics test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPUon.png)
I got information from the doc about Hive column statistics. For most of columns have filed bitVectors, what's the mean of it, and the rule to calculate it?

I create some tables and use analyze statement to calculate statistics. I show the column statistics, find most of columns have this filed(bitVectors), the value is null/HL, i don't know what it mean.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was introduced in Hive 3.0.0 by [HIVE-16997 - Extend object store to store and use bit vectors](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16997) and still is not fully documented. Bit vectors in statistics metadata can be used for calculation of the number of distinct values (NDV) using sketch algorithms (FM-sketch, HLL).

Also corresponding parameter was added to allow using stats bit vectors for NDV calculation:

```
hive.stats.fetch.bitvector

Default Value: false
Added In: Hive 3.0.0 with HIVE-16997
```

Whether Hive fetches bitvector when computing number of distinct values (ndv). Keep it set to false if you want to use the old schema without bitvectors.

See here: [hive.stats.fetch.bitvector](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.stats.fetch.bitvector)

Also you can google and find some info about sketch algorithms: FM and HLL. For example this [Flajolet–Martin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flajolet%E2%80%93Martin_algorithm)

Comment: What i got from your answer is hive.stats.fetch.bitvector can control whether use bitvector calculate NDV. Can i know for which kind of column when i use 'analyze table $tb_name compute statistics for columns' statement can got bitvector? Because after execute analyze statement,for some columns have no value, some columns have value HL.

Comment: HL is the same null : While adding stats with null bit vector, a special string "HL" is added as 
> Postgres does not support null value for byte columns. But while getting the 
> stats, the conversion to null is not done. This is causing failure during 
> deserialisation of bit vector field if the existing stats is used for merge.   See here https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@hive.apache.org/msg213529.html

Comment: And I do not know why bitvector is not being populated